# What is this small black spider found in NY?

Tags: species-identification

I found this small, black, spider with a yellow mark at the top of its abdomen, crawling on my desk in my office (located in the Lower Hudson valley in NY). I have never seen a spider like this before.

[image: Black hairy spider with yellow mark on top of abdomen]

What is this spider, and is it native to NY, or is it an invasive species?

Comment: It is hard to see in the picture, but did the spider have 3 distinctive yellow marks in its abdomen. If so, it could be a jumping spider.

Comment: I did some searching on line, and see it looks like phidippus audax, but it didn't seem to do any jumping.

Comment: Jumping spiders are the largest family of spiders on Earth; now that you've seen one, I'm pretty sure you'll notice them around. And they almost all look like this, but with different coloring, sizing, and back leg modifications. And, yes, they can and do jump when they need to, though it's more like a hop. A scary hop, when they are trying to scare you off. They make *me* jump.

Comment: If one of the answers below have answered your query, consider accepting it by clicking the **green checkmark**, giving you and the other user some reputation points. This aids in closing the question as solved. There is no obligation to do it either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It resembles a juvenile ***[Phidippus audax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phidippus_audax)***, of the family **[Salticidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_spider)**.

[image: Spider]

**Image Source**: **[SpiderZule](http://www.spiderzrule.com/daring.htm)**

According to **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phidippus_audax)** >>

> They are typically black with a pattern of spots and stripes on their
>   abdomen and legs. Often these spots are **orange-tinted in juveniles**,
>   turning white as the spider matures.

***Phidippus audax*** is a *[common jumping spider in North America](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/bold-jumper)* and definitely not an invasive species.

Comment: Are the number of spots on the abdomen variable? I am sure the one in my picture had only one, not three like the one in the image you provided.

Comment: @lzam There are varying patterns for the distinctive markings, ranging from strokes to spots. Most [commonly observed](https://www.google.ca/search?q=spots+on+jumping+spiders&safe=strict&client=ms-android-samsung&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbpouOlsDTAhXoz1QKHfTpD14Q_AUIBygB&biw=360&bih=560#imgrc=_) are a collection of 3 spots with one of them being bigger than the rest of them. I cannot be sure, but maybe the number and type of spots change during maturation - this guess can be made because the color of their  spots does change on maturation. Again, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It is the Bold jumper, Phidippus audax. The “Bold Jumper” is one of the largest and  common species of jumping spider in North America. The spider is mostly black with a white, orange, or red triangular patch in the center of its abdomen.